# 404 On NextJs Static Files

Tags: iis, next.js

I have a next js project that works fine with `npm run dev`.
it also works fine with `npm run build` and then `npm start`
it also works fine on localhost on the server.
but no css, or images, or any files works when it's on the domain.

[image]

I'm running it on IIS, windows server 2019 with plesk panel

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Have you checked if the Request URL is correct?

It might be the issue regarding relative path / absolute path.

Comment: I alreaddy fixed the issues by replacing the files locations, but it all done mannualy, I have to take all images out of public folder, take _next folder out of out folder and ...
all by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, and made it running by following:

1. Check the Document Path, Application Root, and Application Startup file on Node.js Dashboard inside the Plesk.

It looks like this on my server.
[image: Node.js Dashboard on Plesk]

2. Also update your next.config.js file with the code below to enable static export.

   const nextConfig = {
   output: 'export',

   }

   module.exports = nextConfig
3. Run npm install and npm build commands and it should work.